# How to view windows files while running Ubuntu from a CD?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive

After crashing, my windows laptop stopped booting up correctly (it boot loops instead of booting into windows). I used a windows recovery disk, and saw via the console that files could still be viewed so the hard-drive is not broken.

My goal is to back up my files before attempting to fix the windows install.

I currently have Ubuntu running from a CD (version 12.04 LTS) on it, but how do I access files from the hard-drive so I can back them up?

So far I've tried `fdisk -l` which lists 3 partitions `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` but I can't mount them (it says the device doesn't exist) and when I `cd` to `/dev/sda` they aren't listed - only `sda` is which also won't mount (it says it's the wrong file system type no matter which file system type I use).

How can I access the files on my hard drive?

Comment: you may need the `ntfs-3g` package, depending on Ubuntu version for the partitions to mount.

Comment: @D0rf: I'll try that - would not having it cause the partitions to not *show up* under /dev/ though? I'm using the latest ubuntu release btw

Comment: @D0rf: this did not work. It's still not showing up in /dev.

Comment: I got a feeling that your hard disk have fail and beyond repair even though it can detect it.

Comment: Maybe you can try to do a NTFS fix by issue this command `sudo ntfsfix /dev/<device name>` and then issue a `sudo ntfs-3g -o force,rw /dev/<device name> /media/windows` Let me know if it works.

Comment: Also, look inside the `/mnt` to see if it is already mounted in the first place or not. (e.g. `/mnt/sda1`)

Comment: @Jack: Thanks! It's not in mnt (in fact I did a find * | grep for sda1 and nothing came up). I will try the other suggestions asap - restarting computer first to ensure nothing i've been trying before this gets in the way. Also if it has failed beyond repair, how is it that when I boot with the windows repair tool it can see and read all my files?

Comment: @Jack: those fixes did not work. In both cases I get the error "ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error"

Answer (score 0):

after your live CD or USB have boot successfully click on **Try Ubuntu** button and when it was loaded just click on the folder shape icon in the left panel (this is called **Nautilus**) and see if your windows drives are listed under **Devices** in the left pane of Nautilus. click on them and you can see/access your files.

ntfs-config is an **unmaintained and obsolete piece of software** and is not needed for mounting the windows partition just mount them from Nautilus.

if this didn't work run this command in a terminal and post the output so i can see if there's anything wrong with your fstab file:

`$ cat /etc/fstab`

EDIT:

following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=137740) tutorial should sort this out for you. it has a section for manual mounting but make sure to read it entirely.

Comment: That did not work. The contents are: https://gist.github.com/cammckinnon/5516564 - do you have any ideas?

Comment: did you follow the tutorial?